# realm react native error Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk'

Tags: react-native, realm

I am working by react native last version 0.62
and want to initialize realm 5.0.0.

after steps to setup realm on react native project i faced this error:

> Failed to compile
>   D:/code/react/realm/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js Module not
>   found: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in
>   'D:\code\react\realm\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.